# Is there a way to get jadclipse working with Eclipse 3.4?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, jad

I'm a big fan of the Jadclipse plugin and I'd really like to upgrade to Eclipse 3.4 but the plugin currently does not work. Are there any other programs out there that let you use jad to view source of code you navigate to from Eclipse? (Very useful when delving into ambiguous code in stack traces).

Comment: Turns out that I installed eclipse in a new location and didn't have the plugin installed... everything else appeared to work because most of it was just in my workspace preferences. My bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm successfully using JadClipse with Eclipse 3.4

Eclipse 3.4.0.I20080617-2000
JadClipse 3.3.0

It just works!

EDIT:
Actually, see [OlegSOM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122110/is-there-a-way-to-get-jadclipse-working-with-eclipse-3-4/224779#224779) below for the additional steps that you might need to remember to take, if like me you forget to read documentation sometimes!

Comment: Sweet. Eagerly awaiting them.

Comment: Just to let everyone know that I have just got JadClipse 3.3 working with Eclipse 3.5. Very easy. Downloaded the jar, dropped it into the plugins. Downloaded Jad. Edited the preferences and pointed JadClipse to Jad and Bingo. That easy.

Comment: Make sure you run eclipse with "-clean" like they tell you to. That's what fixed any problems for me.

Answer (score 20):

Read attentively the documentation ... :

1. The JadClipse plug-in is not activated when I start Eclipse.
   You'll need to launch Eclipse with the -clean flag to allow the 
   environment to detect   the plug-in. Subsequent launching of 
   Eclipse won't require the -clean flag. 
   **eclipse -clean**
2. The Eclipse Class File Viewer instead of the JadClipse Class File Viewer is 
   opened. Go to **Window > Preferences... > General > Editors > File Associations** 
   and make sure that the JadClipse Class File Viewer has the DEFAULT file 
   association for *.class files. ( -  press Default button !!!)

It really helps :)))

Comment: This is what I forgot to remember after upgrading to Eclipse 3.6

Comment: Helped me to get jadEclipse to work with eclipse 3.6! thanks.. :)

Comment: Even after perfoming mentioned things, it gives me JAR HAS NO SOURCE ATTACHMENT message. (I am using STS 3.7.0).

Answer (score 7):

update your eclipse 3.4 for jadeclipse from help-> software updates
http://webobjects.mdimension.com/jadclipse/3.3
restart the eclipse.
set the jadeclipse properties.
it doesn't just works.. this is the solution.

Comment: This solution works for me. Downloading the jar and manually placing it into the plugins directory (as suggested on their website) did not work for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind my question above - my problem was my settings for the path to jad.exe and the temp directory.

In case anyone else has the same problem I did, make sure the path to the decompiler is correct (like "C:...\jad.exe") and leave the temp directory alone (for me it's "C:\Documents and Settings{user}.net.sf.jadclipse").

This is a pretty good utility - infinately more useful than the default class viewer!

Answer (score 1):

I can't get to make the plugin work with ganymede (linux version).
When setting the jadclipse class viewer i get the following error in the log file of the workspace (.metadata/.log)

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
        at net.sf.jadclipse.JadclipseClassFileEditor.doOpenBuffer(JadclipseClassFileEditor.java:101)
        at net.sf.jadclipse.JadclipseClassFileEditor.doSetInput(JadclipseClassFileEditor.java:45)
        at net.sf.jadclipse.JadclipseActionBarContributor.setActiveEditor(JadclipseActionBarContributor.java:87)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorActionBars.partChanged(EditorActionBars.java:335)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$3.run(WorkbenchPage.java:628)
.....(i don't think the rest of the stack trace is important)
```

Perhaps jadclipse isn't compatible with the version of its eclipse dependencies (on this line jadclipse makes a call to a class defined in the JDT plugin), but i didn't have the time to figure this out.

EDIT: i've simply recompiled the jar using the svn repository and created a new jar for java 1.5 and it seems to work ([Download here](http://lancelotdm.free.fr/files/net.sf.jadclipse_3.2.4.LdM.jar)). Just download my jar and put in the plugin folder of eclipse and remove the old one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Was facing the same error in Europa with JDK 1.5. Your jar works well.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem running JadClipse in Eclipse Ganymede. It turns out the Groovy plugin had conflicted with JadClipse. After removing the groovy plugin, JadClipse ran just fine. Btw here's the problem:

```
Cannot complete the request.  See the details.
Unsatisfied dependency: [org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.feature.feature.group 2.0.0.20090814-1100-e34-N] requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.core.help/[2.0.0.20090814-1100-e34-N,2.0.0.20090814-1100-e34-N]
Unsatisfied dependency: [org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.feature.feature.group 2.0.0.20090814-1100-e34-N] requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.codehaus.groovy.jdt.patch.feature.group/[2.0.0.20090814-1100-e34-N,2.0.0.20090814-1100-e34-N]
Unsatisfied dependency: [org.codehaus.groovy.jdt.patch.feature.group 2.0.0.20090814-1100-e34-N] requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group/[3.4.2.r342_v20081217-7o7tEAoEEDWEm5HTrKn-svO4BbDI,3.4.2.r342_v20081217-7o7tEAoEEDWEm5HTrKn-svO4BbDI]
Unsatisfied dependency: [org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.core.help 2.0.0.20090814-1100-e34-N] requiredCapability: osgi.bundle/org.eclipse.help/3.3.102
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just able to successfully install jadclipse with Ganymede.  In order to do this I:
1) Installed via the help-> software updates http://webobjects.mdimension.com/jadclipse/3.3

2) Put the Jad executable into a directory that is in the execution path of your operating system. Alternatively, you can configure the path to the Jad executable under Window > Preferences... > Java > JadClipse > Path to Decompiler. (Set the full path, e.g. C:\Program Files\Jad\jad.exe)

3)Go to Window > Preferences... > General > Editors > File Associations and make sure that the JadClipse Class File Viewer has the default file association for *.class files.

4) Restart Eclipse (eclipse -clean).

It is now working perfectly for me!

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me is that I went to Window > Preferences... > General > Editors > File Associations and reset the default. I set the default to "Class File Viewer" and the back to "Jadclipse Class File Viewer". No it works for some reason. :)
If you're out of luck, try that.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions in this link

http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/22657

But when downloading the jadclipse plugin for Eclipse from 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jadclipse/

Just download this jar
"net.sf.jadclipse_3.3.0.jar" and put it in the Eclipse plugins folder
 The rest is the same way it is in the first link.

Answer (score 0):

I have it working on Eclipse as well:

Version: 3.4.1
Build id: M20080911-1700

The plug-in install steps are straightforward - http://jadclipse.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page#Installation

I had to download JAD itself from a mirror site (original site is gone?) - http://www.varaneckas.com/jad

I'm on a Windows machine, which might matter.

Answer (score 0):

I followed bhupendra's method (add via Help > Software Updates > http://webobjects.mdimension.com/jadclipse/3.3) and it worked for me.  Using the jar file directly (even restarting with -clean) didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the problem :

Go to Window > Preferences... > General > Editors > File Associations and make sure that the JadClipse Class File Viewer has the default file association for *.class files.

Restart Eclipse (eclipse -clean).

Answer (score 0):

using this update site with myeclipse 8.5 seems to work fine:

http://webobjects.mdimension.com/jadclipse/3.3

FYI Jeff