# JADClipse not working with Eclipse 3.6

Tags: java, decompiling, eclipse-3.6, jad, jadclipse

Does `Jadclipse` work on `Eclipse 3.6`?

I have installed `Jadclipse 3.3.0` on my `Eclipse 3.6` by copying the jar into the **plugins** directory and restated eclipse.

Now I have the **jadclipse** menu under **Windows->Preferences** but when trying to de-compile any class it simply does not de-compile. I get the usual eclipse screen saying the source is unavailable. There are no errors in the **Error Log**.

Any idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I eventually found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122110/is-there-a-way-to-get-jadclipse-working-with-eclipse-3-4/224779#224779).

Running eclipse with `-clean` switch and setting the file association between `*.class` and the `jadclipse` plug-in solved the problem.

Comment: File Association can be set in Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations, change the associated editors for "*.class without source" (sorry, had to search for a few minutes, thought I'd help the next one)

Comment: A newer version of JADClipse which supports Juno is now available, more info can be found on my blog post: http://ronkitay.wordpress.com/2012/11/12/jadclipse-is-up-and-running/

Answer (score 6):

Set the JAD path correctly in Preferances>Java>Jad. Ex: D:\Jad\jad.exe

If still not working then,

Go to File extensions in Preferences. Select JadClipse as default editor for .class and .class with out source.

Answer (score 5):

The main reason is that you eclipse have **default class viewer** configured for class file which you have to change to your new class decompiler.

go to preference > editor > choose "**class without source**" and select your tool and mark as default. will work for you :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
Just check if the JadEclipse Class File Viewer is the default viewer for "Class without source" in Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations.

Answer (score 0):

Download jad.exe and then in eclipse there are 2 places to configure.

1. Window->Preferences->java->JadClipse give the path of jad.exe in Path to decompiler
   like C:\Users\Documents\xxx\jad.exe. then Apply
2. Window->Preferences->General->Editors->File Associations. Click on *.class and in below 
   dialog box there should be JadClipse Class File Viewer(default). If not click on Add...
   add JadClipse as default file viewer.
3. Do the same for *.class without source as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issues on mac with STS and was able to fix it with below process.

1. Download JADClipse plugin jar and copy it to plugins folder of Eclipse.
2. Download JAD decompiler and unzip it into a folder on your mac. Set java decompiler to JAD. 
   Eclipse->Preferences->Java->Decompiler->Select JAD
   Eclipse->Preferences->Java->JADClipse->Path to decompiler (/Users/test/Desktop/JavaDecompiler/jad158g.mac.intel/jad)

Select file associations for .class and .class with out source to default JADClipse class viewer.

Restart Eclipse and it should work.

References -> http://hemantasapkota.github.io/posts/setting-up-jadclipse-and-jad-java-decompiler-in-eclipse/

https://eedannak.wordpress.com/2014/11/02/how-to-decompile-class-files-in-java-with-eclipse-ide/