# Not able to see the .class files in eclipse after configuring the Jadeclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, classpath, decompiler

I had configured the Jadeclipse plugin for viewing .class files, but it is still showing "source can't be found" in the particular JAR file.

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [JADClipse not working with Eclipse 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6108607/948268) for help. Also ensure that `Path to decompiler` is correct under `Preferences` in `Java -> JadClipse`.